# Rails 5 ActiveRecord - check if any results before using methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 5 + Postgres app I make a query like this:

```
user = User.where("name = ?", name).first.email
```

So this gives me the email of the first user with the name.

But if no user with this names exists I get an error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass)

How can I check if I have any results before using the method?

I can think if various ways to do this using if-clauses:

```
user = User.where("name = ?", name).first

if user
user_email = user.email
end
```

But this does not seem to be the most elegant way and I am sure Rails has a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by), returns the object or `nil` if nothing is found.

```
user = User.find_by(name: name)
if user
  ...
end
```

That being said you could have still used the `where` clause if you're expecting more than one element.

```
users = User.where(name: name)
if users.any?
  user = users.first
  ...
end
```

Then there is yet another way as of [Ruby 2.3](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-2-3-features/) where you can do

```
User.where(name: name).first&.name
```

The `&` can be used if you're not sure if the object is `nil` or not, in this instance the whole statement would return `nil` if no user is found.

Comment: There's also `try` in Rails if your Ruby doesn't have `&.`: `User.where(name: name).first.try(:name)`. But `try` also swallows NoMethodErrors that don't arise from `nil` so sometimes you'd want `try!` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use `try` a lot to handle just this situation.

```
user = User.where("name = ?", name).first.try(:email)
```

It will return the email, or if the collection is empty (and `first` is nil) it will return nil without raising an error.

The catch is it'll also not fail if the record was found but no method or attribute exists, so you're less likely to catch a typo, but hopefully your tests would cover that.

```
user = User.where("name = ?", name).first.try(:emial)
```

This is not a problem if you use the Ruby 2.3 `&.` feature because it only works with `nil` object...

```
user = User.where("name = ?", name).first&.emial
# this will raise an error if the record is found but there's no emial attrib.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use `User.where("name = ?", name).first&.email`, but I disagree that

```
user = User.where("name = ?", name).first

if user
  user_email = user.email
end
```

is particularly inelegant. You can clean it up with something like

```
def my_method
  if user
    # do something with user.email
  end
end

private

def user
  @user ||= User.where("name = ?", name).first
  # @user ||= User.find_by("name = ?", name) # can also be used here, and it preferred.
end
```

Unless you really think you're only going to use the user record once, you should prefer being explicit with whatever logic you're using.